# Docker Container Loses Connection after short time routed through Host VPN Interface

Tags: docker, linux-networking, wireguard

So I have the following example compose file, with a custom defined network:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      wireguard:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.2
networks:
  wireguard:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: 'wireguard'
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
```

And the following Wireguard config defined as `wg0.conf`:

```
[Interface]
Table = off
SaveConfig = false
PrivateKey = {Client Private Key}
Address = 10.8.0.21/32
DNS = 10.8.0.1

# And create routing manually only for WG related communication.
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -i wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT 1 -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 2 -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostUp = ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup 2
PostUp = ip rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
PostUp = ip route add default dev wg0 table 2
PostUp = sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
PostUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wg0.rp_filter=2

# Removal when `wg0` goes down
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostDown = ip rule del table main suppress_prefixlength 0
PostDown = ip rule flush table 2

[Peer]
PublicKey = {VPN Server Public Key}
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.1/32,0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = {VPN Server Connection Endpoint}
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Now the wireguard connection is setup to route incoming connections back through the wg0 interface, to avoid all of the client connections going through the VPN.

So now my objective is to have **specific** docker containers routed through the VPN connection for their connections out. So what I do is rune the following rule and route in the host shell to add to the existing table:

```
# ip rule add from 172.18.0.0/16 lookup 2
# ip route add 172.18.0.0/16 dev wg0 table 2
```

And if I enter the docker shell and check the connection it works perfectly and shows the IP of the VPN server:
[ping and ip inside docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8237.png)

But after around 30 second to up to 5 minutes, I can't get a connection out and any connection attempts just timeout:
[no connection out docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzFF0.png)

And if I tcpdump the bridge network it just keeps trying to make ARP requests for 172.18.0.1:
[tcpdump container bridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be58v.png)

I have no idea why this happening or how to fix this. I have seen several posts and forums of people doing the same for routing a docker network connection through a specific interface, so I don't know if I've done something wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So likely it was the rule priority that was causing the weird ARP issue, setting the following priorities fixed it:

```
ip rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0 prio 9999
ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup 2 prio 10000
ip rule add from 172.18.0.0/16 lookup 2 prio 11000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do is running the VPN in a seperate docker container and then connect the other docker containers through that VPN. That's at least the best practice.

A example docker compose:

```
---
version: "3.7"
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE #optional
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - SERVERURL=wireguard.domain.com #optional
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=1 #optional
      - PEERDNS=auto #optional
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0 #optional
      - ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0 #optional
      - PERSISTENTKEEPALIVE_PEERS= #optional
      - LOG_CONFS=true #optional
    volumes:
      - /path/to/appdata/config:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules #optional
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
   

  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    network_mode: service:wireguard
```

With `network_mode: service` the Ubuntu container will connect through the WireGuard container with the vpn client. service: This allows a container to share the network namespace with another service. You specify the service name, and the containers will use the same network stack.

---

You can also use `network_mode: host` instead of networks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have considered that but that would increase the size and complexity of my configuration. I would have to create peers for each of my compose environments as well at the moment I have several websites coming in to the one server, some of which are served by apache itself and several of which get reverse proxied to compose containers.

Comment: As for the `network_mode: host`, that would require me to run the entire host network through the VPN wouldn't it? (I may be wrong). I can't do that as I run backups to cloud storage daily, and I'm only given a monthly bandwidth of 1TB outgoing with remote VPS. Plus some of the things I update on the server range in the 100's of GB's.

Comment: My goal with is to have all routing config hopefully only in 2 places, the wg config on the remote server doing the port forwarding and the wg config on the local server, just to avoid having a maintenance nightmare. [See my reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/185fnqk/comment/kg26twf/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: You can still have the wg config on your local server, as the config is mounted as a volume and the rest is done is a docker compose file also on your local server. If you have other workloads running on the server and based on those requirements i would really recommend using a docker vpn client container. The benefit of that is that your other server workloads aren't routed through the vpn and only your docker containers. If you only want route traffic through a vpn there is no need to have the wg config on a remote server, or do you want to have a VPN server?

Comment: The VPN server is just the static public IP for my home server/s, It's just a router for forwarding specific traffic down. It's only that a few of my containers need a connection going out through that IP for registration purposes.

I can't have/ don't want to have all of my container's in a single compose file because a lot of them use the same dependent services. So I'd rather have them separated and on their own subnet, so I'd still have to have a different `[Peer]` config for each.

Comment: If I were to set it up that way I would have to move my apache server to the remote VPN server to simplify things, as it would require the port 80/443 request being forwarded to the main server VPN connection, and then reverse proxied to a peer out back through the VPN connection to come back to a docker container running on the same host.

Comment: If you use different docker compose files you can use network_mode: container:wireguard. That being said,  you can't stretch a docker network over two servers with a different ip this way. For using the VPN you need to have a VPN server active where you connect to. It might be easier to go in a chat room quickly. There might be other ways to route the traffic of that Ubuntu container to that remote host. I will come on that

Comment: in that case it would be: http request made -> remote static ip VPN server -> port forwarded through vpn connection -> local server on 10.8.0.8 apache -> reverse proxy to peer on 10.8.0.9 -> back through tunnel -> reaches docker container peer on 10.8.0.9. it adds an extra 2 connections tunneled through the internet to get to the same machine.

Comment: No incorrect.  First you would need to create a VPN tunnel,if you want to use a VPN. Local host >> Remote Host VPN >> docker container remote host using VPN remote host >> forward to apache reverse proxy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150697/discussion-between-slg-shark6-and-turdie).